# Searching for an arbitrary word with regex

Tags: regex, qt

I have a problem, i need to find a word wich can be in currently format
NormalWord 
or contains digits and - (minus character sign) in the word for example
1Word-withnumber1-Morecharacters.
or containc citation characters
'My word'
I have tried with (qt)
QRegExp rx("((\w+\b)|('.*'))");
but this construction works only for normal word for example SimpleWord or 'Simple word' but not when i have a word like
1Word-withnumber1-Morecharacters
or 
Word1-withsomeMorecharacters

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this: `(\w+(-\w+)*|'.[^']*')`

The `[^']` will match anything except an apostrophe/single quote.